# macOS Catalina LogOn Screen Password is selected and overwritten

Tags: keyboard, password, catalina, login, login-screen

When waking up my MacBook Pro (Early 2015 Retina) with newest macOS version installed, I am usually very quick typing in my password. However, when in the middle of entering my password the whole password that I have typed so far is selected and as I press a new key, the part of the password that I have already typed is overwritten. Has anyone had similar problems or knows some solution to this problem?

Comment: Any inadvertent mouse/trackpad clicks/drags ?

Comment: I can confirm this issue. The macOS login screen is very laggy. There is some feature to "highlight the entire password" so that your next keystroke overwrites it... but this often occurs *after* you have time to type several characters.

Comment: Possibly related to: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155305/mac-boots-into-log-on-screen-quickly-but-takes-long-time-to-log-into-account